# How can I multiplex my asp.net web application under load?

Tags: .net, linux, windows, iis, devops

This question is not a request to solve my question instead of me. I wonder your idea and experiences. Is it possible replication web app or server under pressure old heavy load.I made lots of research but I couldn't find any application or sample. Because of that, I don't know it's possible to create a web application or web server under request presure or heavy loaded.

For example I have a web application 192.168.5.1:8080 under IIS when Request becomes alot response time getting longer, I want to create a yml file like that:

```
if(request.Count>4000){
startReplicate.new.WebApp(192.168.6.2:8080);
startReplicate.new.WebApp(192.168.5.1:8081);
}
if(request.Count>8000){
startReplicate.new.WebApp(192.168.6.3:8083);
startReplicate.new.WebApp(192.168.5.1:8080);
}
```

this is possible or Can I do that Automatically? I mean that multiplexing web apps or crerating new web server.

Comment: Docker and K8s should be something you study. Raw IIS/Windows won't give you anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should go to the host file ,its under the folder etc in windows operation system just write in the hosts file your ip and then click on tab and write you server name